# Basic join query understanding

Tags: sql, mysql, join, left-join

I know this very silly, but can anybody help me in understanding what does this join query is doing in elabortive description?

```
SELECT j1.*
FROM jos_audittrail j1
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_audittrail j2
   ON (j1.trackid = j2.trackid AND j1.field = j2.field AND j1.changedone < j2.changedone)
WHERE j1.operation = 'UPDATE'
  AND j1.trackid=$t_ids[$n]
  AND j2.id IS NULL
```

I know its very silly, but i need to go ahead with my further need...  Pls do help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Left Join` in combination with `j2.id IS NULL` returns only those rows of `j1`, where no row of `j2` can be found.

Since the condition is `j1.changedone < j2.changedone`, it returns only the rows with the highest `changedone` per `trackid` (if there is more than one row with this value of `changedone` for a `trackid`, all of them are returned).

---

So if you have

```
trackid  changedone
      1           1
      1           2
      2           1
```

You will get

```
trackid  changedone
      1           2
      2           1
```

since for `1 - 1` the `Left Join` finds a record (`1 - 2`), so `j2.id` is `NOT NULL`.

Comment: That means if I have multiple values of trackid 1 and 2 both then they will displayed as per maximum changedone value first and then less than that and so on ???

Comment: @OM: Not sure if I understand your comment. As long as `changedone` is unique per `trackid` you will get only one row per `trackid`, the one with the highest value of `changedone`.